# PDO Invalid Data Source Name

Tags: php, pdo

I'm getting 'invalid data source name' when trying to concatenate the array in config.php. It works fine if I hardcode it what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

config.php

```
<?php

return [
    'database' => [
        'host' => 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1',
        'database' => 'pdo_database',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'options' => [
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        ]
    ]
];
```

connection.php

```
<?php

$config = require('config.php');
$database = $config['database'];

class Connection {
    public function make() {
        try {
            return new PDO(
                $database['host'].';dbname='.$database['database'],
                $database['username'],
                $database['password'],
                $database['options']
            );
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `$database` isn't in scope, you need to pass it into the `make` method

Comment: Ok cheers. I'm new to PHP is scope a lot different to JS with scope? You can't access variables outside a class?

Comment: Yep, exactly. PHP doesn't have any variable scope inheritance - variables explicitly need to be passed into functions/methods. Another approach is to use the `global` keyword inside the function to import variables from global scope, but that's something you'll want to avoid wherever possible.

Comment: There are two scopes in PHP: the global scope (variables used outside any function) and local scope (a different scope inside each function). They do not intersect. Read more about [variable scopes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). For your mind sanity stay away from `global` and `$GLOBALS`; you won't regret.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `make()` method can't simply access global variables.  If you pass the `$database` configuration into the `make()` method...

```
public function make($database) {
```

This passes the configuration needed to create a database connection for this set of parameters.

Depending on how your using this class, you could change it to a static method

```
public static function make($database) {
```

and then use it like this...

```
$connection = Connection::make($database);
```